# Data structures for memory manager

Tags: c, algorithm, memory-management, data-structures

I'm writing a memory manager.  I allocate a large chunk of dynamic memory and split it into various sized memory pools.  The size ranges from 8 to 256 in multiples of 8.  When a memory request comes, depending on the size, I allot a memory block from one of the pools.  I maintain a hash table that maps the required size and the memory pool.
I don't want to keep book-keeping information in the allocated memory and so I use a singly linked list per each pool to keep track of the free blocks. 
 My question is
i) As the block size is uniform across all blocks in a memory pool, I have decided not to sort the blocks. i.e. When a memory request comes, I'll allocate the first block in the memory pool and when it's freed, I'll insert it in the front of the free list.  This way, both memory allocation and freeing will be faster. Also, as the block size is the same in a pool, fragmentation won't occur.  Do you see any problem in this?

Comment: May I ask why is it better than the OS provided allocation scheme? Seems like an awfull waste of memory to pre-allocate chunks of memory you don't know if they will be used at all...

Comment: @RafaelDazcal some applications just do that, because OS might not be reliable, for example Mozilla Firefox

Comment: @RafaelDazcal This will be faster than malloc

Comment: @RafaelDazcal That's called lookaside list and it's very useful in certain situations

Comment: @Kupto Unreliable OS? While OS bugs aren't uncommon (I've seen and filed a number of them), a major OS released with a serious bug in the memory manager is more of a fiction. Bugs in such a widely used component are usually caught in testing before the release.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze +1 yes. Such a buggy OS would probably blow up even before it had booted.  Arrays of buffer containers, as suggested by OP, are usually used for performance reasons. I do the same myself in servers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes to have a LIFO stack to hold unused memory blocks that are all the same size is the easiest solution. I did once something like this myself...

I will only give you one advice. While distributing memory like this, *do not give off the pointer to the beginning of your allocated area*. Oh and it is a good idea to have another stack where to shove allocated blocks, so you know which are they.

Comment: I'll store the pointer to the huge chunk.  But why should I have another stack to store all allocated blocks? When the program shuts down, I'll de-allocate the entire chunk.

Comment: First of you will have two stacks that just swap elements (with info about allocated memory) which is much faster than generating new element every time one memory block is freed. You could also consider having the used elements stack ordered.

Comment: But what's the point of having a stack for used elements in the first place?

Comment: Well I suppose that they will be returned once... So you know where to find the data-structure that holds them. If you are not planing on returning the memory back, you could do it all with just one variable... You can also hold some additional info for example who has borrowed the chunk etc.

Comment: Oh.. that. I have a mechanism to find the data-structure to which the freed memory should be returned. I'll take care of it.  thanks for your answer.